# Android get gravity value of textView programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the current gravity value of a textView in Android

I searched a lot on stackoverflow, but only found solutions how to set gravity or how to get things like margin, padding etc.

So how can I get the current gravity of a textView?

**Edit:** It's simply `getGravity()`

Comment: isn't there method `getGravity()` already?

Comment: see my answer @Zoker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my `TextView` :

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This is the method how i am getting the gravity.

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

switch (textView.getGravity())
{
        case Gravity.CENTER:

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CENTER"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;

        case Gravity.TOP:

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TOP"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;

        case Gravity.BOTTOM:

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BOTTOM"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;

        case Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL:

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CENTER_HORIZONTAL"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;

        case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CENTER_VERTICAL"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
    }
```

I am getting `Toast` displaying **CENTER**.

Comment: Yes it was the getGravity, that I somehow missed :D

Comment: It happens.. Happy coding :)

Comment: When I am setting gravity to START. and getting the same from textview using getGravity it does not return START in return. Any idea??